# How to permently assign (reserve) drive letter to SATA Hard Disks which will be mostly turned off (offline)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, drive-letter

I have following setup:

```
C: System, programs and most frequently used data
D: Optical Drive
E: Virtual Drive
four SATA disks which I turn off using HDD switcher.
F: SATA Hard Disk - Data disk - installation files, music, some data.
G: SATA Hard Disk - Movies
H: SATA Hard Disk - Movies
I: SATA Hard Disk - Offline data, some backup, disk is rarely turned on.
J: IDE Hard Disk - Used for Windows backup (C and F disk) (It can't be turned off)
K: Printer SSD card slot
L: Printer USB slot
M: USB devices
```

Now the problem is when I turn off disks usually they lose drive letter. This especially happens when all disks are turned off and I plug in some USB device even though I set USB to M: it still changes it to lowest letter by some reason. This happens as well when F disk is turned off and I turn on G disk, it changes to F. Because of this I rarely now turn off F disk because it will cause problems when backup day comes and I don't see point to change backup disk from IDE to SATA because of this.

So is there a way to permanently assign (reserve) drive letters?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the drive a letter in disk management. Control Panel->Administrator Tools->Computer Management-> Disc Management is @ the bottom.

Or you can run this command to open it: diskmgmt.msc

You can select the drive and the drive letter that you want to set that drive to. Even if you removed the drive from the machine, once you plug it back up, it will still have the same drive letter.

Comment: "Even if you removed the drive from the machine, once you plug it back up, it will still have the same drive letter." This is not exactly true. If you have multiple drives, or attached drives/devices and you turn off more than one, the next one to go back online takes the lowest letter regardless of what you previously set it to.

Comment: The key here is that **all** the devices which can be plugged in or not need to have letters actually assigned.  What's going on is a device without a letter assigned gets the next available letter.  A device with a letter gets that letter if available, otherwise the next available.  If you can't ensure no strange devices will show up (and most people can't) leave space for them earlier in the alphabet than any of your devices that come and go.

Answer (score 1):

Drives directly attached to the machine start at A and grab the next available letter, network shares (or mappings, if you prefer) work their way backwards from Z to A.  So you really want to pick something in the middle of the alphabet...

You can do what nate suggested, or if you don't want to mess around in a GUI do it all in the command line:

```
diskpart
list volume
select volume 3  <or whatever>
assign letter=q
```

and hit enter.

Now every time that computer sees whatever is plugged in as volume 3 it will get letter q.